# Double sum of products of integers up to $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

Suppose that $S$ is defined by
$$
S(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{i} ij.
$$

I'm confused as to how $S(3) = 25$ from this summation.  Can anyone expand on it as to how to get the answer?

Comment: I edited your question to include the definition of $S$.  Click on `edit` yourself to see the MathJax formatting.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
  S(3) &= \sum_{i=0}^3\sum_{j=0}^i ij \\
       &= 0\sum_{j=0}^0 j + 1\sum_{j=0}^1 j + 2\sum_{j=0}^2 j + 3\sum_{j=0}^3 j \\
       &= 0 + (0+1) + 2(0+1+2) + 3(0+1+2+3) \\
       &= 25.
\end{align*}
More generally,
\begin{align*}
  S(n) &= \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^i ij \\
       &= \sum_{i=0}^n i\cdot\frac{i(i+1)}{2} \\
       &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^n i^3+i^2 \\
       &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} + \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right) \\
       &= \frac{1}{24}(3 n^4+10 n^3+9 n^2+2 n).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a table of the values, where the row is indexed by $i$ and the column is indexed by $j$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|rrrr}
ij & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & 0 \cdot 0 & & & \\
1 & 1 \cdot 0 & 1 \cdot 1 & & \\
2 & 2 \cdot 0 & 2 \cdot 1 & 2 \cdot 2 & \\
3 & 3 \cdot 0 & 3 \cdot 1 & 3 \cdot 2 & 3 \cdot 3 
\end{array}
$$
The way the sum written in your definition of $S$ suggests summing across the rows, so
$$
S(3) = 0(0) + 1(0+1) + 2(0+1+2) + 3(0+1+2+3) = 25.
$$
However, it's worth mentioning that sometimes sums over two indices are easier to evaluate by "transposing" them.  (I don't claim that it's easier in *this particular sum*, but it's useful to see this in action.)  In this situation, you would read down the columns:
$$
S(3) = (0+1+2+3)0 + (1+2+3)1 + (2+3)2 + (3)3 = 25.
$$
In other words, this is an equivalent way to write the definition of $S$:
$$
S(n) = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \sum_{i=j}^n ij.
$$